# Algebraic number with conjugates having modulus 1

Tags: field-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Suppose $\alpha$ is an algebraic number lying in a number field $K$ that is a normal extension of $\mathbb{Q}$. Suppose all the conjugates of $\alpha$ have absolute value 1. Prove or disprove that it is a root of unity.

I could do this for algebraic integers. In case $\alpha$ is an algebraic integer, then one can prove the above by getting a bound on the coefficients of the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$. This limits the number of such polynomials and proves the result. Can we generalise this argument to prove the above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is true if $\alpha$ is an algebraic integer (as you said), but is false in general. Consider $\alpha=\frac{3+4i}{5}$.

Comment: Right! This was easy. Thanks.